# (PHP + MySQL) Pulling point score from MySQL database

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to "relearn" PHP since it's been a long time ago since I last looked into this.

I'm making a small game where users can register and login and guess a number when they're logged in.

When registering they're assigned 10 points. Once logged in there's this little game with 10 buttons (1 to 10) and the rules are simple: each time you push a button a random number is generated, and if that number matches your buttons number you've won 1 point. If not, 1 point is lost.

So, when the user is logged in I pull their points from the MySQL database via a session username and presents it like this:

```
    // Get point
// Prepare a select statement
$sql = "SELECT points FROM users WHERE username = ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);

    // Set parameters
    $param_username = $_SESSION["username"];

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if($stmt->execute()){
        // Store result
        $stmt->store_result();

        // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
        if($stmt->num_rows == 1){                    
            // Bind result variables
            $stmt->bind_result($points);
            if($stmt->fetch()){
                $currentPoints = $points;                     
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    } else{
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
}
```

And when they've gained a point I add it via `UPDATE` and again, if they lost one point I do an `UPDATE` to the SQL database.

So my question is - is this the correct/most efficient way of doing so? I mean, it seems like a whole of MySQL requests with constant `SELECT` and `UPDATE` requests to the server.

If anyone can point me in a better direction, I'd appreciate it a lot :-)

Comment: It sounds like this may be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: First of all, use PDO. Then, you might want to ajaxify this: On button press, sent the request via Ajax, and also listen for the response via Ajax. (No constant page reload). Also: maybe store the points in JavaScript first and only make changes to the database at the end of the session/if player has no points anymore.

Comment: @TimB, I'll look into PDO - thanks! I understand your point, but if I only commit the changes to the database at the end of a session, what happens if the user just quits his browser?

Comment: @David - my bad! Thanks for pointing me in that direction! :)

Comment: @doingSomeSwiftHere you can listen for page closing events etc. But either way, you should definitely ajaxify your game.

Comment: I'll look that up. Thanks, Tim!